# Running mysql_ssl_rsa_setup generates an error

Tags: mysql

In Windows Server 2008, I was running the program with following command:

```
E:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin>mysql_ssl_rsa_setup --datadir="E:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\SSL"
```

It returns this error:

> Unable to load config info from "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\ibm\icc\cimom\bin\openssl.cnf"
>   2018-01-17 10:45:51 [ERROR]   Error generating ca_key.pem and ca_req.pem

The user account has full control to the path. Please help out.

Comment: Try to set the environment variable `OPENSSL_CONF`: `set OPENSSL_CONF=E:\path\to\file\openssl.cnf`.

Comment: Yes, I did set variable "OPENSSL_CONF" but still ran into the error.